# SQL query to filter value using associative entity

Tags: sql

I'm working on this educational system in which the professor table stores the subject ID, career and subject are stored in their own tables and I have the career_subject associative entity because the system assume that the same subject may belong to several careers. The tables look something like this:

- CAREER(id, name, quota)
- SUBJECT(id, name, exam_date)
- PROFESSOR(id, name, subject_id)
- CAREER_SUBJECT(career_id, subject_id)

So, how do I get the name of the career the professor may teach using SQL?

I'm trying with

```
SELECT name FROM career
   INNER JOIN career_subject ON career_subject.subject_id = career_subject.subject_id
   WHERE professor.subject_id = subject.id;
```

Comment: People are down-voting your question because you haven't made an attempt. Remember that SO is not a code writing service. If you were to provide a decent attempt at the SQL query someone will likely help make it work

Comment: fixed, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.name as 'Professor', c.name as 'Career' FROM professor p
   INNER JOIN career_subject cs ON cs.subject_id = p.subject_id
   INNER JOIN career c ON c.id = cs.career_id
```

Comment: Also note that you should tag the question with the specific flavour of SQL you're using. I have assumed MSSQL in my answer, but you might be using something else, so you may need to adjust the syntax accordingly

Comment: If you want an ANSI SQL answer, simply remove the single quotes from the column aliases. (ANSI SQL has double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"Professor"`. Will perhaps be accepted by MS SQL Server too.)